# How to call a function inside a data-bind?

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

How to call the `getStatus()` function again inside this view code snippet after clicking a button?

The only thing that works form me is if I refresh the whole page.

```html
<div id="statusContainter"data-bind="css:$data.getStatus('Rendered Approval')">&nbsp;</div>
```

Basically, I want the `getStatus('Rendered Approval')` to fire if I click a button. The function is firing during initial rendering of the page. But I don't want to refresh the whole page to fire the function

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? your code is confusing because you are using the `css` binding but calling a function called `getStatus` - usually you would use observable values to toggle different classes in a css binding, not call a function with a parameter. Can you describe what you're trying to do in a bit more detail, please?

Comment: the reason that I am using a css binding is because i need to show a status if it is green,yellow or red, what I need to achieve is the status changes from red to green without refreshing the whole page

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `getStatus` is a knockout observable the code you have there ***sets*** the value, but only once. To ***get*** the value of an observable you call the function with no argument.

It sounds like you meant to do this:

```html
<div id="statusContainter"data-bind="css:$data.getStatus()">&nbsp;</div>

<button data-bind="click: $data.getStatus.bind($data, 'Rendered Approval')">Click to Refresh</button>
```

---

**Update:**
 As [@Brother Woodrow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3808667/brother-woodrow) mentioned, the `click` binding expects a function for the handler. Passing parameters to the handler can be accomplished by wrapping it in a function literal  or by using the `this` function as [described in **Note 2** here](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html).

Comment: That's not gonna work though, since the click binding expects a function reference. So it would be `click: $data.getStatus.bind($data, 'Rendered Approval')`.